# node.js, блок try-catch не ловит ошибку в текущей функции, но в функции которая ее вызывает

Tags: node.js, функции, рекурсия, try-catch

Я пишу приложение на node.js/express/mongoDB, если кратко описать суть, то сейчас я создаю функцию которая генерирует токен, с помощью которого можно будет проверять почту пользователя. Вот проблемный код:

**Caller.js:**

```
/* 
   Функция сreateToken() возвращает обьект: err - в слушае ошибки (error message),
   data - в случае успеха (true), status - в случае ошибки (500, 404...). 
*/
try{
  let {err, data, status} = await createToken(userID);
  if(err) callback(err, null, status); // Передаем информацию об ошибке дальше
  else callback(null, true);  // Всё хорошо, нет ошибок, передаем информацию дальше
}catch(err){
  console.log(err);
}
```

**createToken.js**

```
async function createToken(user_id){
try{ 

  let newToken = new Tokens({ // Создаем обьект токена
     user_id: user_id,
     token_id: generateSomeId() // Генерируем id для токена
  });
  await newToken.save(); // Cохраняем созданный токен в базу данных
  return {err: null, data: true};// Если всё хорошо, возвращаем обьект с пустой ошибкой.

}catch(err){
  if(err && err.code == 11000){ //Если токен с таким id уже существует
     createToken(user_id); //Вызываем эту же функцию ещё раз (рукурсия), чтобы сгенерировать другой id
  }else{
     return {err: 'Something went wrong', data: null, status: 500} 
     /*Если ошибка другая, возвращаем сообщение об неизвестной ошибке*/
  }
}
}
```

**Что данный код должен делать**

Для генерации уникальных `id` для токена я использую `uuid4` - он достаточно безопасный, и уникальный, поэтому вероятность возникновения двух идентичных `id` очень мала. Но даже учитывая это, я сделал обработку такой ошибки - (Если вдруг токен с таким id уже существует) теперь если такой токен уже есть в базе данных, мы вызываем эту же функцию (`createToken()`) ещё раз, тем самым, сгенерируется новый `id` токена.

В этом примере вместо `uuid4` я использую свою функию для генерации id - `generateSomeId()`, эта функция имеет только два уникальных значения: ['a', 'b'] - Функция рандомно возвращает значение из этого массива, тоесть может быть только два уникальных токена, если эти два уникальных токена созданы, и мы попытаемся создать третий токен, то мы постоянно будем попадать в блок `catch(err)` в блок, который вызывает сам себя, тем самым, эта функция будет вызывать себя бесконечно.

**Что на самом деле он делает**

Так и происходит, но так же есть и ошибка, причину которой я не могу найти:
При создании первого токена всё идёт хорошо, токен создается с `id: 'a'` (например) и сохраняется в базе данных. При создании 2-го токена, если сгенерируется другой id, допустим `id: 'b'` - тоже всё хорошо, но если сгенерируется токен с id который уже существует в базе данных, то выполнится блок `catch(err)`, блок где вызывается рекурсия (там где мы вызываем функцию `createToken()`), за тем эта функция опять выполнится сначала, и когда доходит до строки с `await newToken.save();` то я получаю ошибку:

`TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'err' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.`

Эта ошибка возникает в модуле который вызывает функцию `createToken()`, то есть в `Caller.js`, в блоке `catch(err)`. Эта ошибка говорит что в возвращаемом обьекте из `createToken()`, свойство `err` равно `undefined`, как и в свойстве `data` и `status`.

**Вопрос**

Я не знаю почему так происходит? Почему при вызове рекурсии `createToken()` я получаю эту ошибку, которая говорит что свойства возвращаемого обьекта равны `undefined`? Разве ошибку не должен поймать блок `catch(err)` в функции `createToken()`? Как я могу решить данную проблему? Целый день ищу причину но безрезультатно. Буду очень благодарен если кто-то понимает в чем может быть ошибка. Заранее Благодарю !)

Comment: Было бы неплохо вызов `createToken(user_id);` также делать с `await`

Comment: @Anatoly, Вот спасибо !, проблема была только в этом, я совсем забыл про `await`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рекурсивный вызов `createToken(user_id)` необходимо делать с `await`:

```js
if(err && err.code == 11000){ //Если токен с таким id уже существует
     await createToken(user_id); //Вызываем эту же функцию ещё раз (рукурсия), чтобы сгенерировать другой id
  }else{
     return {err: 'Something went wrong', data: null, status: 500} 
     /*Если ошибка другая, возвращаем сообщение об неизвестной ошибке*/
  }
```

Comment: Только что попробовал, всё было хорошо в случае когда первый раз генерируется `id: 'a'` (например), а второй раз генерируется другой `id: 'b'`. Но если второй токен сгенерируется с таким же значением `id` как и первый, то вызывается рекурсия, генерируется другй `id`, и сохраняется в базу данных, но вместо того что бы вернуть успешный `return{err: null}` появляется опять эта ошибка в модуле `Caller.js`, хотя код после `await newUser.save();` выполняется, но не return а ошибка.

Comment: Вы никак не возвращаете значение и не используете возвращаемое значение внутри самой функции

Comment: да, только что исправил. Благодарю за помощь !

Answer (score 1):

Рекурсия тут не нужна, она лишь усложняет понимание и поддержку кода

```
async function createToken(user_id) {
  while(1) {
    try {
      const newToken = new Tokens({
        user_id: user_id,
        token_id: generateSomeId()
      });
      await newToken.save();
      return { err: null, data: true };
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.code != 11000) {
        console.error(err);
        return { err: 'Something went wrong', data: null, status: 500 };
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, ваше решение действительно улучшает понимание и поддержку кода. Почитал немного про [recursion vs iteration in Javascript](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/179863/performance-recursion-vs-iteration-in-javascript), и понял, что итерация лучше рекурсии, особенно в моем случае.